# Full width background image sizing issue

Tags: css, web, background-image, fullscreen

I am looking to fix my second full width image (the one in the middle of the page) so that is fits horizontally the same as the one above in the header image. I noticed that there is a gap on the right hand side of the image as seen in the picture below. Is this cause my image is not 1600px wide? I can edit it so that it is 1600px if need be. If the problem is something else can someone help me out. Thanks.

http://www.jobspark.ca

```
.fullWidthSectionBG { 
background-image: url('http://static.squarespace.com/static/513d5347e4b0abff73be5264/t/519c45c4e4b084baf13d7e27/1369195972115/rocktruck2.jpg');
border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd; 
border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
margin-left: -1600px;
margin-right: -1600px;
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:330px;
overflow: hidden;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto; 
} 


<div class="fullWidthSectionBG">
<div class="fullWidthSection">
<div class="myLeftColumn">        
<p>
</p> 
</div>
<div class="myRightColumn">
<h2>Used By Thousands Of Canadians</h2>
<p>Jobspark.ca is dedicated to providing resources for job seekers and employers throughout British Columbia and Alberta. Many top employers along with small local businesses from across the region post their jobs on Job Spark to find qualified professionals.</p>
<p>Job Spark simplifies your quest for the perfect career with a clean design and real-time postings. Our streamline job board was designed to take the headache out of finding a job.</p>
<p>Your job listings will be seen across multiple venues, receiving thousands of views each month! </p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us the HTML as well.

Comment: Ok updated and included html

Comment: When I use this css it does not quite work for my mobile device as it does not cover the entire section. Any idea on how to fix the CSS

Answer (score -1):

These days, you can add this to your CSS styles:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Then you don't have to worry too much about the size of the image. It doesn't work in older browsers, but that's a minor thing these days.

That might not be the look you are after, but in that case, try resizing the image (in this case, perhaps making it less tall). There are other background-size options, too, which are worth checking out.

Comment: Ok thanks. Should I still resize my image to a width of 1600px though?

Comment: If you wish, but it's not a big issue. The user can have their browser window open to wider than that, though, so you just end up chasing your tail a bit.

Comment: Do not use this CSS. Any browser older than IE9 will fail and over 50% of population is still using IE < 9. IE9 is just **18.17%** of total market share. Definitely NOT a minor thing. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size and http://www.netmarketshare.com/

Comment: IE8 and lower still occupies ~50% ( 48.13% ) of total market share. Data last updated : April, 2013

Comment: ok thanks for the reference sites. Can you show what CSS you would use then.

Comment: @Shivan What nonsense. Your link is 3 years old! IE8 currently has 10% market share and dropping. http://www.sitepoint.com/browser-trends-april-2013-is-chrome-unstoppable/

Comment: @ralph.m Net Market Share is updated every month and it is a well-known trust-worthy source. Read the website carefully. The report in sitepoint.com contradicts with ie6countdown.com results which is created by Microsoft itself. By the way, mind your words.

Comment: I see you've updated your link by three years. SitePoint uses the data from [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201303-201303-bar), which is considered very reputable. It's is alarming that the info from those sites is so divergent. Anyhow, NetMarketShare doesn't indicate the division of usage within IE. Most browsers in use support background-size, and even those that don't will still display the background image in a reasonable fashion, so to write it off is not helpful.